# Strange Connection refuse from HBase

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hadoop, hbase

I'm getting a very strange exception while connecting from my remote to HBase server from a java client. Strange thing is that my this HBase server is working fine and i had done a lot of work with it and all the work that i have done is by connecting remotely. But today this server is messing up with me i don't know why. I have checked logs of Hbase but didn't find any exception and when I jps on my HBase server i found that all processes are running fine.Then what is the problem? I also have format the Namenode but problem is still occurring. Exception which is coming while connecting from my java client to HBase server is given below:

```
Hbase Demo Application 
12/05/16 14:22:52 WARN hbase.HBaseConfiguration: instantiating HBaseConfiguration() is deprecated. Please use HBaseConfiguration#create() to construct a plain Configuration
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32 GMT
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=aliraza-desktop
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_26
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=.:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/hbase-0.90.4.jar:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:hadoop-core-0.20.205.0.jar:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/opt/COM/hbase-0.90.4/lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=i386
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-21-generic
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=COM
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/COM
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/opt/COM/hbase-sample
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.15.20:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.15.20:2181
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hbase/192.168.15.20:2181, initiating session
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hbase/192.168.15.20:2181, sessionid = 0x13754f410eb0003, negotiated timeout = 180000
12/05/16 14:22:53 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
    at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1258)
    at HBaseDemo.main(HBaseDemo.java:55)
HBase is not running!
Execution script exiting
```

I really get stuck there.

Comment: Yes I have checked but i didn't found any exception in those logs

Comment: Check your /etc/hosts file. Hbase client uses hostnames not ip addresses.

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue. Make sure port 2181 is open.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?